# Bake target path into setup.py

Tags: pip, python-packaging

I want to install a wheel into a folder, e.g. `/opt`

I'm well aware that this could be achieved by

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/opt" $wheel
```

For design reasons I would like to bake this into my wheel, so I could do

```
pip install $wheel
```

instead. I have studied the [setup script documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) but have found no reference to such an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is impossible. Even more so if the project is distributed in *wheel* format.

Such tasks are better solved at the level of the system package manager of the Linux distribution. We are talking about Linux here, right? So my recommendation is to look into apt/deb, yum/rpm, pacman, etc.

Comment: Yep, Linux. I thought maybe I could do it this way and then use wheel2deb for an easy solution.